# How to maintain unique sessions? Tracking individual logins?

Tags: php, session

Here's my code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {



 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
 $log = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM loggedin") or die(mysql_error());
     while($cols = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
         $value = $cols['email'];
         $email[$index] = $value;
         $index++;
     } 

 session_start();
 $user=session_id();
 }
```

It was working before. But right now, when I have someone log into a user from a different computer and then I log in, it does not give the second user a session id.

If I were to take the if(isset) conditional out, it would then create a new session along with new session id but that same id would then be applied to the first user that logged in.

Why is this happening, and how do I make it so that each logged in user has a seperate session id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each session has its own, unique session id. You should not care about the value of the session id, other than know that `session_start()` uses it to find the previous session. Your code does not do anything useful, but a proper way of handling users logging in would be something like the following, in psesudo-ish code.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))
{
    $user = fetch_user_from_database($_POST['email']);

    if (!$user)
    {
        // display error about user not found (or wrong password)
    }
    else if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password_hashed']))
    {
        // display error about incorrect password
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
    }
}
```

When you want to check if someone is logged in, do `!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])`, when logging someone out use `session_destroy` and `session_regenerate_id`. Either fetch the user information on each request from the database, or store the complete user row / object in the session, depending on which tradeoffs (an extra DB lookup vs handling stale data / larger session object) you want to live with (unless you're doing high traffic sites, just do whatever). If you go with storing the whole user in the session object, unset the password hash or other sensitive information before doing that.

Since you want to track users across multiple sessions, you have to have some way of identifying them when creating the session, and an email/username/password combination is the usual way to do that.

Comment: Ill try this out. So I can store multiple ids/usernames in $_SESSION['stuff here']?

What confused me is that, I had my colleague log in on chrome from her computer in a different location. Then when I logged in, when it saw the (!isset) conditional it saw it as false,and didnt run the code. But when I took away that conditional, it then set the session_id for my login to the same session_id for her login.

Comment: Also, I have my loginpage.php seperate from my main page. So it goes from login.php to dahsboard.php. Do I have to run session_start() again on the second page?

Comment: @user3486712 Yes, $_SESSION is not available until `session_start()` is called, although some installations may have `session.auto_start` set to 1, making session_start() being called automagically when $_SESSION is accessed. You can however not rely on this, and should call session_start yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `uniqid()` to the session id .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no other session_starts in your codebase?

Not really sure what your code does, but would this work out for you?

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
    $log = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM loggedin") or die(mysql_error());
    while($cols = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
         $value = $cols['email'];
         $email[$index] = $value;
         $index++;
    } 

    $user = session_id();
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
 }
```